# OnCreate and Onbindviewholder is not calling on recyclerview

Tags: android, google-maps, android-recyclerview, google-maps-api-2

I'm using google maps api, while I'm trying to set places name and images on `RecyclerView`, also using bottomsheet and viewpager, I want to fetch the data while app lunch , actually i got results showing nearest places and how to i set the name and images on recyclerview..?
actual problem is not calling the `onCreateViewHolder` and `onBindViewHolder` while calling the adapter..!! 
sample code is here

**MainActivity.java**

```
protected void onPostExecute(Place[] places) {
            mHMReference.clear();
            mPlaces = places;
//            List<HashMap<String, String>> onlineData = mPlaces;

            Place place;
            for (int i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {
                place = places[i];
                Log.e("Place", String.valueOf(place));
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(place.mLat);
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(place.mLng);
                Log.e("PostEx Lat" + lat, "Long" + lng);
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                Marker m = drawMarker(latLng, BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE);
                        }
            int v = mHMReference.size();

            dm = new DisplayMetrics();

            for (int j = 0; j < mHMReference.size(); j++) {
                Log.e("Loop out", String.valueOf(mPlaces[j]));
                placeDeta = mPlaces[j];

                viewPager = (CustomPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
                ViewPagerAdapter adapterPager = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
                adapterPager.addFragment(new CurrentPlace(), "Current Location");
                adapterPager.addFragment(new NearestPlace(), "Nearest Places");
                adapterPager.addFragment(new CategoryPage(), "Category");
                adapterPager.addFragment(new SuggesionsPage(), "Simler Places");
                viewPager.setAdapter(adapterPager);
                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

                NearestPlace nearestPlace = new NearestPlace(placeDeta, dm);
                FragmentManager fm1 = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft1 = fm1.beginTransaction();
                ft1.add(nearestPlace, "TAG");
                ft1.commit();
            }
        }
    }
```

The above code have  two constructor call

**Fragment.java**

```
public class NearestPlace extends Fragment {
    Place mPlace ;
    DisplayMetrics mMetrics = null;
    private WindowManager windowManager;
    String url;
    View rootView;
    int i=0;
    public List<HashMap<String, String>> onlineData;
    public NearestPlace(){
        super();
    }
    public NearestPlace(Place place, DisplayMetrics dm){
        super();
        this.mPlace = place;
        this.mMetrics = dm;
        Log.e(" call dialog ", String.valueOf(mPlace));
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ViewGroup con=container;
        Bundle bd=savedInstanceState;

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nearestlocation, container,false);
        Log.e("Mplace!!!!", String.valueOf(mPlace));

        if(mPlace!=null){

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycleviewNearestlocations);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        RecycleViewAdapterNearestLocations RecycleViewAdapterNearestLocations;
        RecycleViewAdapterNearestLocations = new RecycleViewAdapterNearestLocations(mPlace, getContext());
        Log.e("MplaceURL", "dd " + mPlace);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(RecycleViewAdapterNearestLocations);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        }

        else{

            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"No data found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }



        return rootView;
    }

    public WindowManager getWindowManager() {
        return windowManager;
    }

}
```

Adapter class

**RecycleViewAdapterNearestLocations.java**

```
public class RecycleViewAdapterNearestLocations extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleViewAdapterNearestLocations.ViewHolder> {
    static Context home;
    Place mPlace;
    int i;
    private List<Place> mData = new ArrayList<>();

    public RecycleViewAdapterNearestLocations(Place mPlace, Context context) {
        this.mPlace=mPlace;
        this.home=context;
        i=1;
        Log.e("detailsofREC","place : "+mPlace);

        if(mPlace!=null){
        Toast.makeText(home,i+" Name ::"+mPlace.mPlaceName,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{

        Toast.makeText(home,i+" Name null!!"+mPlace,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,int viewType) {
            View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycleviewnearest, null);
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
            DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = home.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
            int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
            Log.e("card","width:"+width);
            Log.e("card","height:"+height);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            viewHolder.itemView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        return viewHolder;
        }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        Log.e("Onbindview", String.valueOf(mPlace));

        if(mPlace!=null){

        Toast.makeText(home,i+ " TAG Name "+mPlace.mPlaceName,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            viewHolder.txtViewTitle.setText(mPlace.mPlaceName);
        }
        else{

            Toast.makeText(home,i+" TAG Name NULL!!!"+mPlace,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            i++;
        }


    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    public ItemData mItem;
    public TextView txtViewTitle;
    public ImageView imgViewIcon;

    public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
        super(itemLayoutView);
        txtViewTitle = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.txtNearestPlaceName);
        imgViewIcon = (ImageView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.imgNearestPlaceBackground);
            itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void setItem(ItemData item) {
        mItem = item;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(home,DetailPage.class);
        home.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 5;
    }
```

mPlace values like this :com.example.user.myapplication.classes.Place@38c8eb1f

[Using this tutorials](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-nearby-places-with-photos-at-any-location-in-google-maps-android-api-v2/)

and how to I set the Place name in `RecyclerView`

Please help me, Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem with your code is:

1. You are passing only single place to adapter

   Solution. pass list of places then only it will show you list of places.
2. getItemCount should return size of your listItems that you are passing in adapter

   Solution. `return listPlaces.size();`

follow this Tutorial and adapter of this example and then pass your listPlaces in this and modify, It will work.

https://www.learn2crack.com/2016/02/image-loading-recyclerview-picasso.html

Hope it will help.